# How to translate following comparator into Comparator.comparing?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, comparator

My question may be unclear so let me clear it out by example:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>(){
    public int compare(String a, String b){
        return (b + a).compareTo(a + b);
    }
});
```

I want to use the Comparator.comparing. I tried out the following:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing((a, b) -> (b + a).compareTo((String)a + b)));
```

I get an error - bad return type in lamdba expression. How to fix this ?

Comment: You wouldn't use `Comparator.comparing` here because `comparing` takes a function that would transform one `String` element into a Comparable. `comparing` would not let you have access to both elements at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered, your anonymous class implementation can be shortened into a lambda expression:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a, b) -> (b + a).compareTo(a + b));
```

If you **insist** on using `Comparator.comparing()`, remember it has specific parameters that don't fit your sorting problem.

- The [`Comparator.comparing(keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) returns a specified `Comparator` for certain key based on the natural way of comparison ([`Comparator.naturalOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--)). Your method doesn't say **what** is compared, but **how** it is.
- The [`Comparator.comparing(keyExtractor, keyComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-)  looks a bit better because you can specify **how** the specified keys are compared using `keyComparator`. You can use your logics of comparing and you conclude to:

  ```
  Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(
      Function.identity(),                  // keyExtractor, WHAT is compared
      (a, b) -> (b + a).compareTo(a + b))); // keyComparator, HOW is it compared
  ```

  This is a solution using `Comparator.comparing` that uses a `keyExtractor` the `Function.identity()` returning the input back (the same like `str -> str` lambda expression) since you want still compare the Strings but in a different way specified with a custom `Comparator`, therefore the only correct way to sort the array as you need is the simplified version omitting the `keyExtractor`:

  ```
  Arrays.sort(arr, (a, b) -> (b + a).compareTo(a + b));
  ```

  ... which is finally where we started at.

Answer (score 6):

`Comparator.comparing` method expects a `keyExtractor` of type `Function`. You just need a lambda to implement the `Comparator<String>` interface here:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a, b) -> (b + a).compareTo(a + b));
```

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to turn that into a call to comparing because it's not a valid Comparator: it doesn't satisfy the Comparator contract, and you should never use it as a Comparator.

To prove it, that Comparator will compare every string as equal to "", but not every string will be equal to each other.  That violates the transitivity property.